# Systemd inside rootless podman container possible?

Tags: systemd, podman

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a **rootless podman** container with systemd enabled **inside** the container (not to be confused with a systemd service controlling the container itself on host-system-level!)? If yes, what would I need?

This is a simple `Dockerfile` I've been trying to run as non-privileged user (runs fine as root!)

```
FROM ubuntu:focal         
                  
RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
  init

# Start the systemd Init service by default
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
```

I noticed that during `$podman build -t foo:latest .` the following happens. This also happens as root user btw so might not be problem related:

```
...
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service → /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/remote-fs.target → /lib/systemd/system/remote-fs.target.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-resolved.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/resolv.conf': Device or resource busy
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ondemand.service → /lib/systemd/system/ondemand.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-pstore.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service.
Initializing machine ID from random generator.
Cannot set file attribute for '/var/log/journal', value=0x00800000, mask=0x00800000, ignoring: Input/output error
...
```

Running a container using that image via `$podman run -d foo:latest` results in a 255 error which I am unable to debug further. `podman ps` output:

```
427b3ce050dc  localhost/foo:latest                  /sbin/init            6 seconds ago   Exited (255) 7 seconds ago                            quirky_poincare
```

My podman version is 3.3.1. Anyone any idea on whats happening here? As already stated, building and running the same container under the same Dockerfile **as root** results in perfectly working systemd inside the container!

### Update

I got it working enabling `lingering` for the user via `loginctl enable-linger $user`:

> Enable/disable user lingering for one or more users. If enabled for a specific user, a user manager is spawned for the user at boot and kept around after logouts. This allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services. Takes one or more user names or numeric UIDs as argument. If no argument is specified, enables/disables lingering for the user of the session of the caller.

See the [manpage](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/loginctl.html) for further details

Comment: Yes, it should be possible. What Podman version are you using? What command are you using? Do you see any error message?

Comment: thx  @ErikSjölund I've added some further information to the original post!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it possible to run **Systemd** inside a rootless Podman container.

I tried out your example with **Podman 3.4.1** on a **Fedora 35** laptop. It seems to work. Maybe you encountered some bug that later got fixed in a newer Podman version?

```
[testuser@laptop ~]$ cat /etc/fedora-release 
Fedora release 35 (Thirty Five)
[testuser@laptop ~]$ podman --version
podman version 3.4.1
[testuser@laptop ~]$ mkdir testdir
[testuser@laptop ~]$ cd testdir
[testuser@laptop testdir]$ emacs Dockerfile
[testuser@laptop testdir]$ cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:focal         

RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
  init

# Start the systemd Init service by default
CMD ["/sbin/init"]
[testuser@laptop e]$ podman build -t foo:latest .
STEP 1/3: FROM ubuntu:focal
Resolved "ubuntu" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/ubuntu:focal...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob 7b1a6ab2e44d done  
Copying config ba6acccedd done  
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
STEP 2/3: RUN apt-get -qqy update && apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install   init
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Selecting previously unselected package libapparmor1:amd64.
(Reading database ... 4127 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../00-libapparmor1_2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapparmor1:amd64 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcap2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../01-libcap2_1%3a2.32-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcap2:amd64 (1:2.32-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libargon2-1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../02-libargon2-1_0~20171227-0.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libargon2-1:amd64 (0~20171227-0.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../03-libdevmapper1.02.1_2%3a1.02.167-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.167-1ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libjson-c4:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../04-libjson-c4_0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libjson-c4:amd64 (0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libssl1.1:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../05-libssl1.1_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcryptsetup12:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../06-libcryptsetup12_2%3a2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libip4tc2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../07-libip4tc2_1.8.4-3ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libip4tc2:amd64 (1.8.4-3ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libkmod2:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../08-libkmod2_27-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libkmod2:amd64 (27-1ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package systemd-timesyncd.
Preparing to unpack .../09-systemd-timesyncd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Selecting previously unselected package systemd.
Preparing to unpack .../10-systemd_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up libapparmor1:amd64 (2.13.3-7ubuntu5.1) ...
Setting up libcap2:amd64 (1:2.32-1) ...
Setting up libargon2-1:amd64 (0~20171227-0.2) ...
Setting up libdevmapper1.02.1:amd64 (2:1.02.167-1ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libjson-c4:amd64 (0.13.1+dfsg-7ubuntu0.3) ...
Setting up libssl1.1:amd64 (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.9) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Readline
debconf: (Can't locate Term/ReadLine.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Term::ReadLine module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30.0 /usr/local/share/perl/5.30.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.30 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.30 /usr/share/perl/5.30 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base) at /usr/share/perl5/Debconf/FrontEnd/Readline.pm line 7.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Teletype
Setting up libcryptsetup12:amd64 (2:2.2.2-3ubuntu2.3) ...
Setting up libip4tc2:amd64 (1.8.4-3ubuntu2) ...
Setting up libkmod2:amd64 (27-1ubuntu2) ...
Setting up systemd-timesyncd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.timesync1.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-timesyncd.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service.
Setting up systemd (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/getty.target.wants/getty@tty1.service → /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/remote-fs.target → /lib/systemd/system/remote-fs.target.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/systemd-resolved.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service.
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/etc/resolv.conf': Device or resource busy
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/ondemand.service → /lib/systemd/system/ondemand.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sysinit.target.wants/systemd-pstore.service → /lib/systemd/system/systemd-pstore.service.
Initializing machine ID from random generator.
Selecting previously unselected package systemd-sysv.
(Reading database ... 4939 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../systemd-sysv_245.4-4ubuntu3.13_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Setting up systemd-sysv (245.4-4ubuntu3.13) ...
Selecting previously unselected package init.
(Reading database ... 4956 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../archives/init_1.57_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking init (1.57) ...
Setting up init (1.57) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
--> 8365295f680
STEP 3/3: CMD ["/sbin/init"]
COMMIT foo:latest
--> c5943cdefb8
Successfully tagged localhost/foo:latest
c5943cdefb8da63207de2195d08a00588ba1a725c9203f0642d2d070c505e717
[testuser@laptop testdir]$ podman run -d foo:latest
717f98bc12cd59297073985582f1c4cbc5718595da66ac8a1ee750b9e44bba10
[testuser@laptop testdir]$ podman logs 717f98bc12cd59297073985582f1c4cbc5718595da66ac8a1ee750b9e44bba10
[testuser@laptop testdir]$ podman container list
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                 COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS             PORTS       NAMES
717f98bc12cd  localhost/foo:latest  /sbin/init  15 seconds ago  Up 15 seconds ago              laughing_nobel
[testuser@laptop testdir]$ podman container list
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                 COMMAND     CREATED         STATUS             PORTS       NAMES
717f98bc12cd  localhost/foo:latest  /sbin/init  31 seconds ago  Up 31 seconds ago              laughing_nobel
[testuser@laptop testdir]$ podman container list
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                 COMMAND     CREATED        STATUS            PORTS       NAMES
717f98bc12cd  localhost/foo:latest  /sbin/init  4 minutes ago  Up 4 minutes ago              laughing_nobel
[testuser@laptop testdir]$
```

#### Update September 8, 2023

I could also mention that my laptop uses  [*cgroup v2*](https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/common/cgroup2/#checking-whether-cgroup-v2-is-already-enabled)

```
$ ls /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers
/sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.controllers
```

(I don't know if this is important information for the example)

Comment: I got it working by using `loginctl enable-linger <USER>` for the host system user, according to the manpage it `"[..] allows users who are not logged in to run long-running services.[..]"`. I'm gonna research on that a little further and update my post. Thanks so much for showing it is possible at all, had me keep trying ;)

Comment: Bumping podman to 3.4 made no difference btw!

Comment: Why don't you get `Failed to mount cgroup at /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd: Operation not permitted` ??